# Qatar - Is it a visa rejection?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, qatar

I applied for a Qatar A3 e-visa via the Hayya.qa online portal. However, my application was rejected because I only uploaded photo of the biometric page of my passport instead of both pages in 1 picture.

I then updated (that's what the portal had as a functionality) my application with picture of both pages after this notification (but it produced a different reference Id), and my visa was approved within minutes.

Given the rejection notification at first, I'm concerned if I have to state this in "have you ever been refused a visa" questions in subsequent visa applications I file later on (I obviously don't want to carry this mental burden for life).

Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your visa application was not complete and therefore the application was **not accepted for further processing**.

After suppyling the requirements for the application, the application was accepted  and processed.

The result was that the visa was granted.

> In case the link might not be obvious: BECAUSE your visa was not further processed, it did not come to the point of rejection. Hence, the answer is NO.
> *as noted in a comment by **Zsolt Szilagy***

Comment: Great answer. In case the link might not be obvious: BECAUSE your visa war not further processed, it did not come to the point of rejection. Hence, the answer is NO.